# How to extract a portion of a page and write to a new PDF file in itext7?

Tags: pdf, itext7, text-extraction

I want to divide a PDF page in to 4 quadrants. Then write each quadrant in to separate PDF page (or a document). I don't want to crop the existing page, but extract the contents of each quadrant and write it in to a new PDF file. Is there a way to do this using itext7?

Comment: *"I don't want to crop the existing page, but extract the contents of each quadrant and write it in to a new PDF file"* - in what way does that exclude cropping? Having four copies of the page and cropping each individually should do, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

I want to mention that the documentation for itextsharp and itext7 is bad and lacking in many ways - the book "iText in Action 2nd Edition" is the only help, if you are willing to read a book, and the examples are only in Java and some of the code is implemented in a different way in C#, not to mention that this is only on itextsharp 5.

For future reference - assuming you need equal parts split, here is what will do the trick( this is for 4x4 - that is 16 parts):

```
public void manipulatePdf(string src, string dest)
    {  
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        iTextSharp.text.Rectangle pagesize = reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1); 
        Document document = new Document(pagesize); 
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, 
            new FileStream(dest, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite)); 
        document.Open();  
        PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent; 
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, 1); 
        float x, y;  
        
        for (int i = 0; i< 16; i++) 
        {    
            x = -pagesize.Width * (i % 4);    
            y = pagesize.Height * (i / 4 - 3);    
            content.AddTemplate(page, 4, 0, 0, 4, x, y);    
            document.NewPage();  
        }
        document.Close(); 
    }
```

Comment: *"the book "iText in Action 2nd Edition" is the only help"* - you might be surprised if you took a look at the itextpdf web site, in particular the KnowledgeBase there. That being said, your code is for itext 5, not itext 7.